# Copying an audio file to the internal memory of the phone from the raw folder

Tags: java, android

The question arose, how could I save the audio file from the raw folder of the project to storage / emulated / 0 / My folder / ___. Mp3 on the emulator. Everything works with text files, but not very good with audio (There are audio files in .mp3 in the raw folder), help, please explain.

Activity:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityThree.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE}, 1);
try {
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Моя папка");
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
    }
    String text = "m"+"1";
    String textok = readRawTextFile(this, getResources().getIdentifier(text, "raw", "com.bla-bla.dev"));
    File gpxfile = new File(root, "Мой файл.txt");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
    writer.append(textok);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Файл сохранен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Help please, really would be grateful!

Comment: `if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
    }` Change to: `if (!root.exists()) {
       if ( ! root.mkdirs()) {Toast(..sorry could not create directory...); return;}
    }`

Comment: `readRawTextFile` You did not post the code but an audio file is no text so no wonder things go wrong. You should just read the bytes from raw and write them to file. Thats all. You cannot first put the audio file in a String variable.

Comment: Did you google android copy file from raw ?

Comment: Yes, I heard that you need to write an audio file to bytes. I tried to do this, but it did not work. Could you, if not difficult, share a piece of code?

Comment: google android copy file from raw

Comment: But first: adapt your mkdirs() code. Also here!

Comment: I'm understood, thank you